# How to create a Parameter Store entry without a value in AWS CDK?

Tags: aws-cdk, aws-ssm

In AWS CDK, you can create a parameter store entry for storing secrets like passwords.

However you cannot leave the value blank, and you shouldn't put the secret in the CDK git repository, so how do you get the entry created?

I am currently doing something like this:

```
const paramKey = new cdkSSM.StringParameter(this, 'example-key', {
    description: 'Example SSH private key parameter',
    parameterName: 'example-key',
    stringValue: `???`, /// What goes here?
    allowedPattern: '^-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----[^-]*-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----$',
});
```

In this case, I can't leave the `stringValue` blank or I get an error, as Parameter Store does not allow blank values.  The only value it will accept is an RSA private key, due to the `allowedPattern` requirement (which is a safety measure to stop someone from accidentally putting in an invalid value through the AWS CLI).  But I don't want to put my private key in as it should not be part of the CDK git repository.  I don't want to use a dummy key as then someone might think the correct key has been entered already.

How can I deploy a blank Parameter Store value while having the `allowedPattern` present?

The only workaround I have come up with is to hack the value to allow another token as well, like this:

```
const paramKey = new cdkSSM.StringParameter(this, 'example-key', {
    description: 'Example SSH private key parameter',
    parameterName: 'example-key',
    stringValue: `TODO`,
    allowedPattern: '^TODO$|^-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----[^-]*-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----$',
});
```

This means the Parameter Store entry will accept either an RSA key or the value `TODO`.  But this seems very hacky so I am wondering whether there is a proper solution for this?

Comment: You could KMS encrypt the value you want to use as a string parameter and then store the encrypted version in your repo and decrypt at runtime

Comment: @AnonymousAlias That gets complicated though when you want to deploy the same code to multiple environments (e.g. separate AWS accounts for test/staging/production) as you then have to figure out what environment you're running in.

Comment: What you do there is either have profile configuration files or when creating the string parameter name append the name of the environment to the end of it  - `string-parameter-key-name-{env}`  in your code.

Comment: Do you have to create parameter in CDK? A common pattern I've seen is people would create parameter manually (precisely for the reason to not store anything in code) and then in the CDK you would just get ssm value

Comment: @TofigHasanov: That would also work, but it means you have to re-deploy when you change the SSM value. If you keep the SSM lookup at runtime to avoid that, then you have to manually update the IAM policy for SSM every time you deploy a new Lambda, unless you don't follow best practice and leave the permissions fairly open. You could probably create the SSM manually and then import it into the CDK though, then proceed as normal. I do however like the idea of being able to deploy to a new AWS account, run a few CLI commands to set the SSM values, then very quickly everything is up and running.

Comment: Why not just create a secret instead?

Comment: @Luke: Because then your secret ends up in your code, which ends up in your git repository, which is considered bad practice.  Even worse if you want to make your git repo public.

Comment: How about creating the secret stack, and adding the secrets via the console?

Comment: @Luke: That's what the workaround in my question does :)

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ssm-readme.html#creating-new-ssm-parameters-in-your-cdk-app):

> Parameters of type SecureString cannot be created directly from a CDK application; if you want to provision secrets automatically, use Secrets Manager Secrets (see the @aws-cdk/aws-secretsmanager package).

That being said, Secrets Manager doesn't natively support generating RSA key pairs.

I typically create such resources manually, then when I need to reference them in CDK, use the ARN.

Another option which might work for you is to use the [EC2 `CfnKeyPair` construct](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ec2.CfnKeyPair.html). The documentation for this construct states:

> When you create a new key pair, the private key is saved to AWS Systems Manager Parameter Store, using a parameter with the following name: /ec2/keypair/{key_pair_id} .